# Is it possible to find the equation that links two sets of numbers?

Tags: relations

I have two sets of numbers:

$
A = {161, 184, 202}, B = {0.398631, 0.520661, 0.627513}
$

Is there a way (other than trial and error) to find the equation that turns set A into set B?

The order of the numbers in the sets is correct (i.e., 161 relates to 0.398631).

For reference, set A is a list of RGB values and set B is their corresponding values as they're stored in a rendering program. I'm hoping to figure out how to turn the RGB values into numbers the program can understand.

Comment: Could be some luminance calculation, for instance, $(\alpha\text R, \beta\text G, \gamma\text B)$, in which case $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are independent. Some resemblance to Theon Greyjoy?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $n$ points $(x_n, y_n)$ then [there always a polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) $P$ of the degree at most $n-1$ such that $P(x_i) = y_i$.